# Gazebo: sudo echo $BASE_DEPENDENCIES $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES E: Unable to locate package

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, gazebo-simu

When I trying to install dependencies on ubuntu-20.04

```
sudo echo $BASE_DEPENDENCIES $GAZEBO_BASE_DEPENDENCIES | tr -d '\\' | xargs sudo apt-get -y install
```

I have got this error:

```
-get -y install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libogre-2.1-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libogre-2.1-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libqwt-qt5-dev
E: Unable to locate package libignition-common3-dev
E: Unable to locate package libignition-fuel-tools4-dev
E: Unable to locate package libignition-transport8-dev
E: Unable to locate package libignition-math6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libignition-msgs5-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsdformat9-dev
```